# SELECT DB_NAME(0) Is this possible?

Tags: sql-server

I recently saw that when I issue

```
select DB_NAME(0)
```

there is some answer, and when I check sys.databases there is no DB ID 0, so I think there should be a NULL return. If I select DB_NAME(1000) and there is no db id 1000 the return is NULL.

I noticed that the database I'm currently using is always displayed.

Is this normal? is this a bug or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that any database would have an id of zero, or a negative number. According to the official Microsoft Books Online [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189753.aspx) for db_name():

Arguments:
database_id
Is the identification number (ID) of the database to be returned. database_id is int, with no default. If no ID is specified, the current database name is returned.

So, I would say that the behavior sort of interesting, but that it is undefined and should not be relied on for production code.

I've always used db_name(), with no parameters, to find the name of the current database.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% but shouldnt you use:

```
USE <DBNAME>
GO
SELECT <STATEMENT>
```

If i'm way off sorry about that.

Comment: you made me notice that the database I'm using is the one that gets displayed. So if I:
USE MASTER
GO
SELECT DB_NAME(0)
I get MASTER as answer.
But I'm still wondering why is this, I think this shouldn't happen.

Comment: I think that if the DB ID specified dosnt not exist it simply returns the current database.